# How to improve performance when resizing page with many charts using Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I have an application that displays 70 or 80 charts using Dygraphs.  When resizing the page there is a severe performance issue, sometimes crashing the browser, I'm assuming due to all of the charts attempting to resize and redraw themselves to fit the given space.  If I specify a specific width for the charts it helps a lot, but then the charts don't use the given space efficiently.  Any recommendations on how to improve the performance when resizing large numbers of charts at once and still allow them to fill the given space?

Comment: are you debouncing the resize? in not, do so. If already, hide the charts until 100ms after the last resize.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need.  Is there more info on how to go about that somewhere?

Comment: "debounce resize js" should find some directions...